# how to remove object from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdictionary

Hi i am having a NSdictionary in which i am adding a array with key "countries ". Now i take the value of this dictionary into  array and sort the array in alpahbatical order .Now i want to add this array into my Dictionary (that is i want to update my dictionary with new sorted array and remove the old array from it )........ how to do this

My code is as follows

```
NSArray *countriesToLiveInArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Iceland", @"Greenland", @"Switzerland", @"Norway", @"New Zealand", @"Greece", @"Italy", @"Ireland", nil];
NSDictionary *countriesToLiveInDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:countriesToLiveInArray forKey:@"Countries"];


NSArray *tmpary = [countriesToLiveInDict valueForKey:@"Countries"];
NSLog(@"ary value is  %@",ary);
NSArray *sortedArray = [tmpary sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSLog(@"sortedArray is %@",sortedArray);
```

Here i want to remove the  countriesToLiveInArray and replace it with sortedArray with same key value i.e. Countries
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why not just sort the array before adding it the to dictionary?

Comment: Use objectForKey: not valueForKey:  valueForKEy: is technically for KVC and it's very slightly slower.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

First you need to use a `NSMutableDictionary` and put this code :

```
[countriesToLiveInDict removeObjectForKey:@"Countries"];
[countriesToLiveInDict setObject:sortedArray forKey:@"Countries"];
```

Comment: You don't need to remove the previous object for the key. -setObject:forKey: automatically releases the previous object, if called on a kety that already exists.

Answer (score 6):

First of all make your NSDictionary to NSMutableDictionary & then write the following line of code

```
[countriesToLiveInDict removeObjectForKey:@"Countries"];
```

This will definitely resolve your issue.

Comment: Is setting the `countriesToLiveInDict =` necessary?

Comment: Don't do this, the documentation states `-[NSMutableDictionary removeObjectForKey:]` returns `void`.


See: [- (void)removeObjectForKey:(KeyType)aKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableDictionary/removeObjectForKey:)

Answer (score 1):

`NSDictionary` cannot remove anything, please use `NSMutableDictionary`, like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *countriesToLiveInDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:countriesToLiveInArray forKey:@"Countries"];
```

Answer (score 1):

for Swift 3 
as @MathieuF answered it 
First you need to use a NSMutableDictionary and put this code :

```
countriesToLiveInDict.removeObject(forKey: "Countries")
```

i post my answer as i was search for same question and get inspired by @MathieuF