# How to remove key from nsmutabledictionary When value of that key is empty or null in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutabledictionary

I have created NSMutableDictionary and the values of keys are formed as nsarray. I have removed objects of keys. I have no doubt for this case. But I would like to remove key When value of that key is empty or null as following as the case.

```
{
    Africa =     (
        "Kenya",
        "South Africa"
    );
    America =     (
    );
    Asia =     (
        "India"
    );
}
```

The above dictionary has three keys and one of these keys has no objects that is America. I would like remove this key. Is it possible?
Can we remove key from nsmutabledictionary?

Please help me.....

**Edited:** Simple mistake. I understand what i have mistaken. The key(America) has value and which is empty array that means the number of elements in array is zero.

Comment: [dict removeObjectForKey:@"America"];

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879546/how-to-remove-object-from-nsdictionary

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> The above dictionary has three keys and one of these keys has no objects that is America.

FALSE. It holds an empty `NSArray`.  This is how you remove it:

```
[dictionary removeObjectForKey:@"America"];
```

Comment: @AKV Thank you :) +1 for you too.

Comment: @PrasadG : whenever you see { } that is dictionary, & ( ) are arrays... remember :)

Comment: @AKV Also, he needs to remember that there's no way an `NSDictionary` can hold `nil`. (Let's not talk about CoreFoundation trickery for now...)

Comment: @AKV Yes, I saw that, and that's why you got +1 from me :-)

Comment: Thanks Dwight! :)

Answer (score 3):

> `How to remove key from nsmutabledictionary When value of that key is
>   empty or null in ios?`

This is not possible, dictionary must have Key and Value a non-nil Value.

In your case it is Array. that contains no value.

EDIT:

Whenever you see { }, that is dictionary, & ( ) is array.

Comment: no problem, sometimes it is allowed, not always, Ek Galti Maaf :)

Answer (score 0):

in swift 3.0

```
dictionary.removeObject(forKey: "America")
```